# Using AWS for android and iphone applications

Tags: objective-c, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-mobilehub

I'm trying to set up environments for my companies iphone, android, and web applications. Is AWS compatible to use if it is coded in Obj-C and the android app is in javascript but not react?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this link

https://aws.amazon.com/mobile/resources/

For ios sdk on github

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios

And javascript sdk is

https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/sdk-for-javascript/

Getting started dev guide :

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html

PS:You should always secure credentials for making these